# delete data from mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, starrocks

When I want to delete data for a certain period of time from mysql, I write a piece of sql like this

```
delete from 
    aa 
where date >= date_sub('2024-03-01', interval 3 day) and date <= '2024-03-01';
```

or

```
delete from 
    aa 
where date >= date_format(date_sub("2024-03-01", interval 3 day), '%Y-%m-%d') and date <= '2024-03-01';
```

all reported errors;

Detail error message:

> Getting analyzing error from line 3, column 14 to line 3, column 51.
> Detail message: Right expr of binary predicate should be value.

I want to know how to solve this problem and what caused it. I think the time processing is correct, but I don’t know why it is wrong.

Comment: which mysql version did you use? I check it can run successfully here https://dbfiddle.uk/JPHSyDls?hide=4

Comment: The mysql version I use is 5.1.0

Comment: [\[Bug\] Right expr of binary predicate should be value #21144](https://github.com/apache/doris/issues/21144)? *Detail error message* - this is not MySQL error message!

Comment: I would ask on forum.starrocks.io